# Remove whitespace after certain set of characters

Tags: python, regex, split, substring, whitespace

For example, I want to change the following string

```
strr = 'Hello, this is a test to remove whitespace.'
```

To

```
'Hello,this is a testto removewhitespace.'
```

So the whitespace directly after a comma, 't' or 'e' character should be removed.
I tried something like:

```
re.sub(', |t |e ', ' ', strr)
```

However, this removes the comma, t and e as well.
Afterwards, I am trying to split the string on the remaining whitespaces. 
My first approach was to split like this

```
re.split(' is |a |test|remove', strr)
```

However, this removes the delimiters as well, which is not what I want to achieve. So basically, I want to provide a list of characters followed by whitespace, such that the whitespace in that substring is removed.

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'([,te]) ', r'\1', strr)` or `re.sub(r'([,te])\s+', r'\1', strr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
import re

str1 = 'Hello, this is a test to remove whitespace.'

str2 = re.sub(r'([te,])\s+', r'\1', str1)

print(str2)
```

Should work, where you're matching (and capturing) a known group, followed by any amount of whitespace, and replacing that whole thing with just what you've captured.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*positive lookbehind* [regex-tutorial]](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
re.sub('(?<[,te]) ', '', strr)
```

This positive lookbehind `(?< ...)` block will look for a match, but it will not be *part* of the match, so you do not "eat" the characters when you repace it.

Note that the second parameter, should be the *empty string* (so `''`, not `' '`), since otherwise you "reintroduce" the space.

This then yields:

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=[,te]) ', '', strr)
'Hello,this is a testto removewhitespace.'
```

In case you want to remove an arbitrary number (so one or more) *spacing* characters (spaces, new lines, etc.), you can use the `\s+` instead:

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=[,te])\s+', '', strr)
'Hello,this is a testto removewhitespace.'
```